# What's the notation for a function continuous in its domain?

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have a function that is continuous in every point of its domain, but its domain is only a subset of the real numbers (for example $\mathbb{R}-\{1\}$). Can I say that the function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$? If not, what's the best way to express it?

Comment: What is wrong with "continuous in its domain" or even just "continuous"?

Comment: continuous **on** its domain. No, you can't say it's "continuous on $\mathbb{R}$" because its domain is *not* $\mathbb{R}$. And "continuous *in* $\mathbb{R}$", or even "continuous *in* its domain", just sounds funny.

Comment: If you could say that it is continuous on $\mathbb R$ then where would it stop? You could say e.g. that it is continuous at $\mathbb C$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd say that "f is continuous **on** its domain". No, you can't say that your example function is "continuous on $\mathbb{R}$" because its domain is *not* $\mathbb{R}$ – it omits 1. And "continuous *in* $\mathbb{R}$", or even "continuous *in* its domain", in general just sounds funny.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that the correct word is "on" because english is my second language, so thanks for that also.

Comment: English is a nightmare when it comes to these. You do something _at_ 7:00, _on_ Tuesday, _in_ October. Makes no sense.

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger  Haha I have to agree. I hadn't noticed that blizzard of prepositions -- my sympathies to anyone learning it. Not to mention spelling, which hasn't been revised since the Renaissance (5 different pronunciations of words ending in "-ough").

Answer (score 2):

A function is well defined only if there are specified its domain and codomain. So, usually, to say that a function is continuous means that it is continuous on its domain , and this domain can well be a proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$.